# Youtube Api for wpf windows Application

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube-api

I want to to play youtube Videos in my Window application using wpf. I found a demo project which play youtube video in a webbrowser. But is there any option through which I can play videos in Wpf Application rather than webbrowser.

Comment: Yes there is. Your tagged youtube-api description already tells that: The YouTube APIs and Tools enable the integration of YouTube's video content and functionality into a website, **application**, or device

Comment: @Reniuz thanx for your valuable time.In every where I found You tube Integration for web browser in DotNet.If You have APPLICATION Integration for You tube then can you please share the link

Comment: I spend some time to do your research work. Results: 1. [WebBrowser control is not web application.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF). 2. You can try to use [Shockwave Flash Object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg-z8JfOIKw). 3. You can try to use [vlc.DotNet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) which has already [made example](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Vlc.DotNet/Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.SampleApplication/VlcPlayer.xaml.cs)(see ButtonPlayYoutubeSample method).And that's enough to start play video in your APPLICATION, not in WEB BROWSER.

Comment: @Reniuz thanx for spending time for my work.**I found a demo project** the same project you mentioned 1. WebBrowser control is not web browser.. I can use web browser but because of the limitation of airspace in the control, I am not using the web browser control. Actually I want a pure wpf control which can play Youtube videos

Comment: Still cant understand what you want. What airspace you talking about? Your question is so vague. Please add details what is wrong and what is your requirements.

Comment: I cant show a wpf control over webbrowser control because of airspace issue. My requirement is same mentioned above. My application plays different type of media (image,video,flash etc) in a single screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should have a look to [Youtube-Downloader](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/323771/YouTube-Downloader-Using-Csharp-NET). Use this library to download and cache the video. With the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you should be able to display the downloaded file.

Good Luck!